# SQL: Get the month name from weekcode and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with named "tbl_TimeSheet" with a column of WorkWeek and the data type is nvarchar.

```
   [tbl_WorkWeek]
 1 |  47-2018
 2 |  36-2018
 3 |  1-2019
```

the problem is i'm trying to convert the first digit before the "-" sign to a datename month and having an error message saying "conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1-' to data type int". I can easily get the WorkYear but not the month. I really don't know what to do with that "-" sign.

I'm really new about database and sql. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Current Code: 

SELECT WorkWeek, 
RIGHT(WorkWeek, 4) AS [WorkYear],
DATENAME(month, DATEADD(week, LEFT(WorkWeek, 2) - 1, DATEADD(wk, 
DATEDIFF(wk, - 1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,  GETDATE()), 0)), 0))) AS 
[WorkMonth]  

FROM tbl_WorkWeek
```

Desired Output:

```
     [WorkWeek] | [WorkMonth] |  [WorkYear]
     ---------------------------------------
   1 |  47-2018 |   November  |     2018
   2 |   1-2019 |   January   |     2019
   3 |  36-2018 |   September |     2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using `charindex() and substring()` function

```
SELECT WorkWeek, 
RIGHT(WorkWeek, 4) AS [WorkYear],
DATENAME(month, DATEADD(week, substring(WorkWeek,0,charindex('-',WorkWeek)) - 1, DATEADD(wk, 
DATEDIFF(wk, - 1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,  GETDATE()), 0)), 0))) AS 
[WorkMonth]  
FROM tbl_WorkWeek
```